# Использование зарезервированных слов в классах-константах

Tags: php, php7

Попробовал использовать такие классы

```
class Permits
{
    const PROTECTED = 0;
    const CREATE = 1;
    const UPDATE = 2;
    const DELETE = 3;
}

class MenuPositions 
{
    const DEFAULT = 0;
    const TOP = 1;
    const SIDE = 2;
}
```

PHP не ругается. Проблем пока не было.

Вопрос - чем это грозит? =)

Comment: Разве что путаницей. А так константы классов все равно вызываются через self или имя класса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понимаю, почему вы решили в вопрос вынести именно эти константы. Из них [зарезервированными словами](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) являются только `protected` и `default`. Остальные использованные вами имена констант не имеют специального синтаксического значения в PHP.

До 7.0 зарезервированные слова провоцировали parse error, начиная с 7.0:

> As of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, except that class may not be used as constant name.

Возможно использовать для свойств класса, констант, имён методов, интерфейсов и трейтов. Кроме слова `class`, которое не может быть именем константы и заблокировано отдельным условием.

То есть - на усмотрение разработчика. Мануал заявляет, что парсер разберётся где зарезервированное слово, а где имя константы.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В своем вопросе привел пример классов как они есть. Да, там только protected и default. Остальное не стал вырезать